# Is value X within a range?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number, say `1535.25` stored as variable `possibleDup`, that I'm trying to compare to another number, say `1535` that is the variable `realNumber`.  Both of these will be the same number, only one is going to be rounded/truncated (`realNumber`tends to be truncated, so I can't do a straight numerical comparison).

I'm trying to see if my `possibleDup` number is within 1 of the `realNumber`.  When I do `If possibleDup = realNumber Then ...`, it will seldom run, since one tends to have decimals, and the other not.

Normally, I'd do `If (realNumber + 1) >= possibleDup >= (realNumber - 1) Then ...`, but you can't set up a logic statement like that in VB (AFAIK).

(Alternative ideas are welcome. I have also tried doing `If left(possibleDup,search(".",possibleDup)-1) = realNumber` but my `possibleDup` won't always have a decimal, so I'd have to lengthen my code to account for that).

Maybe setting these values as `String` instead of `Long` and doing a search within the string?

Comment: `If (realNumber + 1) >= possibleDup and possibleDup >= (realNumber - 1) Then` perhaps?

Comment: `if cint(possibledup) <= cint(realnumber+1) and cint(possibledup) >= cint(realnumber-1)` if you want to remove the decimal.

Comment: @findwindow - ahaha, that's it! I just thought of that too, thanks a lot! (TGIF).

Comment: Yea, I am dying to go home too ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `And` operator to chain the conditions of your boolean test:

```
If (realNumber + 1) >= possibleDup And possibleDup >= (realNumber - 1) Then
```

In this specific case, you could do this:

```
If Abs(realNumber - possibleDup) <=1 Then
```